# what percentage of free space should I allot on ext4 volumes

Tags: external-hdd, disk-usage, ext4

Hi I am wondering what percentage of the ext4 volume I should leave empty,or if that is necessary at all for safe storage on large volumes.

I have a 1TB and a 3TB external drives both formatted in ext4

Comment: And you intend to file those 4Tb up with important data?  In how much time do you expect to run out of space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of how EXT4 works, I'd say leave 5-10% free.

Unlike NTFS, EXT4 leaves space between files on the disk platter so that they don't become fragmented when they expand.

You should leave that extra space so that there is ample room to put that spacing between files.